# OSX Apache2 Virtual Hosts Proxy Issue

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, virtualhost

I'm using the following httpd-vhosts.conf file to host several sites on my MacBook.

[Apache Configuration](http://pastebin.com/apjcVw2P)

The first two virtual sites (v3.local,ss.local) are giving back the following error messages in the Apache error log:

[Thu Aug 30 15:12:04 2012] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:3002 (localhost) failed
[Thu Aug 30 15:12:04 2012] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)]

The third site test.local works fine without any issues.

I can't seem to find out why the first two sites are responding with the listed issue. What could be causing it and how can it be resolved?

Comment: What service is supposed to be proxied to?  It looks like it's not listening on port 3002.

Answer (score 1):

Apache is trying to connect to the backends using IPv6, and those backends are likely only serving using IPv4. You'll need to configure apache to connect to 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost, as localhost resolves to an IPv6 address.